# Triggering only certain validations on a particular action with Rails and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, devise-invitable

I have and Administrator model with devise :

```
class Administrator < ApplicationRecord
     validate :max_num_admins, on: :create
     devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
     
       def max_num_admins
         self.errors.add(:base,
          I18n.t(
           'activerecord.errors.models.administrator.max_reached'
          )
         ) if Administrator.count > 3
        end
      end
```

Admins can be added through an admin dashboard by the "account owner", this has the effect of inviting the admin (devise invitable method invite!) :

```
def create
  resource = resource_class.new(resource_params)
  authorize_resource(resource)
  if resource.valid?
    Administrator.invite!(resource_params)
    redirect_to(
      [namespace, resource],
      notice: translate_with_resource('create.success')
    )
  else
    render :new, locals: {
      page: Administrate::Page::Form.new(dashboard, resource)
    }
  end
end
```

As you can see, I want to check if my record is valid, especially if there are no more than 3 admin records for that account. The problem is when I call `valid?` on `resource`(the administrator) I always get false as at this stage the only necessary param to invite an admin is a valid email but devise validations are triggered, and thus I get an error for not setting a password.

What would be a clean way to keep the email and max_num_admins validation triggering for this action but not the password one from devise ?

Answer (score 1):

the validations chain is a chain of callbacks and the result of validations chain is the `errors` after all (return `true` if `errors.empty?`), there's no way to filter (or `fail early`), so when your model setup devise, all devise's validations is add to the validations chain, no way to filter them out but remove devise. So i came up with the idea that you should define a `special validation` scope that will append at the end of validations chain and will force `errors.clear` (so that it'll ignore previous devise validations), take a look at below code:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :confirmable
    
 validate :max_num_admins, on: [:create, :special] # should be the last validation below devise validations

 def max_num_admins
   if self.validation_context == :special
     errors.clear # that mean previous validations (not only devise) be ignored
   end
     
   self.errors.add(:base,
     I18n.t(
      'activerecord.errors.models.administrator.max_reached'
     )
   ) if Administrator.count > 3
 end
end
```

then

```rb
def create
  # ...
  if resource.valid?(:special) # validate at special scope
  end
end

if resource.valid? # this will work as normal
```

**Update**

no need to touch any existed validation, you can add at the end of validations chain a validation `special` that will `slice!` those errors you want to check:

```rb
class User
 # ...
 validate :max_num_admins, on: [:create, :special]
 validate :special, on: [:special]

 def max_num_admins  
   self.errors.add(:max_num_admins,
     I18n.t(
      'activerecord.errors.models.administrator.max_reached'
     )
   ) if Administrator.count > 3
 end

 private
 def special
   # removes all errors except the given keys. 
   # so if you want to check email and max_num_admins
   errors.slice!(
    :email, 
    :max_num_admins
   )
 end
end
```

then

```rb
if resource.valid?(:special) # validate email and max_num_admins
if resource.valid? # check as normal password, email, ..., max_num_admins
```

**note** DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveModel::Errors#slice! is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.2.